# Saving File with CSV extension In External Storage [Xamarin.Froms]

Tags: file, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, export-to-csv

I have data and want to write into csv file and save it in Phone storage.
So i wrote this code to save the file.

```
string csv = Models.CSVHelper.GetCSV<TigerProgram>(item);
        var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), 
        "data.csv");
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(path))
        {
             writer.Write(csv);
        }
```

I'm not getting any exception so i think file is saved but i can only access in runtime using code which i don't want.I want to save in external storage where i can get file easily.so how can i save file in external storage?

Comment: Why are you using `WriteLineAsync` which writes a single line?  Why not just use `File.WriteAllText()`?  And how are you determining that its "not working"?  Are you getting an exception or error?

Comment: Alright i used that but i can't find the file in storage.is there anyway to save file in download folder? Thanks for reply.

Comment: you have to use the DownloadManager API.  You can use ADB to find files saved in app folders.

Comment: can you provide any link for reference? it would be really helpful.or what about the code above how to make it work?

Comment: google for examples of using DownloadManager.  As I just explained, files you write to your app folders can be viewed using adb.

Comment: alright! Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dependency Services to get the Download path from Xamarin.android.Created Interface in Xamarin.Forms and implement it in Xamarin.Android then resolved the interface and got the path Like this

```
var newPath = Path.Combine(DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().GetExternalStorage(), 
"data1.txt");
using (var writer = File.CreateText(path))
{
         writer.Write(csv);
}
```

I also needed to call this method for permissions in `onCreate()` of mainactivity to solve the access denied exception like this

```
private void CheckAppPermissions()
    {
        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 23)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (PackageManager.CheckPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, PackageName) != Permission.Granted
                && PackageManager.CheckPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, PackageName) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                var permissions = new string[] { 
                Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage };
                RequestPermissions(permissions, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

call this in `onCreate()` to solve permission error

Comment: you could mark yourself as a solution,then it will help others.